# I'm attempting a post and getting single quotes randomly in formData

Tags: node.js

Using node.js (0.10.35), and attempting a post

A console.log(formData); shows me a problem, but I can't see why it's happening

Here's a subset of what the console.log shows ...

{ 'ctl00$mainRadScriptManger': 'stuff',
  mainRadScriptManger_TSM: 'more stuff' }

I'm not sure where the quotes around ctl00$mainRadScriptManger come from, and also why mainRadScriptManger_TSM doesn't have quotes.

var formData = {
ctl00$mainRadScriptManger: 'stuff',                                                     mainRadScriptManger_TSM: 'more stuff
}

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will give you some pointers on asking great questions. Here I think helping us recreate the problem with a minimal, complete, verifiable example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an ERROR, nor it is getting printed randomly.

Its because your property name(key) contains '$'.

Putting space in your property name(key) also causes key to be printed in quotes.